# Adding/appending combo-box widget to Tkinter notebook page

Tags: python, tkinter

For the code below, how can I add a combobox `cm` to `tab2` of Tkinter notebook?

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from ttk import *

app = Tk()
app.configure(background='DimGray')
app.geometry('600x600')
app.resizable(width=False, height=False)


note = Notebook(app)

tab1 = Frame(note)
tab2 = Frame(note)
tab3 = Frame(note)

note.add(tab1, text = "Tracing", compound=TOP)
note.add(tab2, text = "Network Details")
note.add(tab3, text = "Tab Three")
note.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

variable = StringVar(app)
variable.set("Select From List")
variable.trace('w', OptionCallBack)

cm = ttk.Combobox(app, textvariable=variable)
cm.config(values =('Select From Phase A', 'Select From Phase B'))
cm.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You do it the same way you add any widget to any other widget. You seem to know how to add a notebook to the app, and frames to the notebook. It's the same concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first variable in any tkinter widget is the parent widget. If you want the combobox in the frame rather than the master, just change the parent:

```
cm = ttk.Combobox(tab2, textvariable=variable)
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan but I am getting empty combo box! do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I just tried the code and it works for me. I'd guess you deleted / commented out the `variable.set` line.